# Getting error with curl while using Bitbucket REST API

Tags: rest, api, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to create a branch using Bitbucket Rest API with curl command as per below

> `curl -X POST -u <username>:<rest api token> "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/projectname/reponame" -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks", "project": {"name": "release1"} }'`

Here is what I have come up with for the curl command Output:

```
url: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'git,'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'is_private'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'true,'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'fork_policy'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'no_public_forks,'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'project'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 14
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

Could you please help where I am missing or correct curl command to create a branch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/branches?_ga=2.192003946.1119205657.1551992715-689242636.1551287875#post

Comment: API documentation lacks an example to understand. Can you provide the command as while using REST API, I am getting 401, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `curl` looks rather that there is a problem with the argument parsing. Please try it again like that:

```
curl -X POST -u <username>:<rest api token> "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/projectname/reponame" -d "{\"scm\": \"git\", \"is_private\": \"true\", \"fork_policy\": \"no_public_forks\", \"project\": {\"name\": \"release1\"} }"
```

Depending which operating system and which terminal you are using the parsing of arguments behaves differently.